# What are Daily Commendations?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

On Belsavis, I found a "Mission Support Vendor" who sells level 50 modifications (and speeders) for Daily Commendations.

What are they? How can I get them? Are they only for level 50 characters?

Comment: Daily Comms have been converted into Classic Comms with the 2.0 patch.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is no longer relevant.  In 4.0, all questing comms up to and including the first tier of endgame are now Common Data Crystals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're awarded for completing a number of repeatable missions which reset daily, and are the primary means of providing your starting endgame gear, as well as socket items for customizable gear at level 50.

There are daily quests on Ilum and Belsavis that award these commendations, and across 13 such quests, you can bring in 17 commendations per day. You can also get some from selected one-time quests, and if I'm not mistaken, a few more by doing flashpoints.

Comment: so swtor IS like wow...

Comment: No, SWTOR is like EVERY OTHER MMO that has ever existed. Saying that is like saying Halo and CoD are the same because they both are in first person...

Comment: Since last week, there is one Space Battle daily that awards two daily commendations as well.